# C# TcpClient - Subsequent calls to StreamWriter only write the first one

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcpclient, streamwriter

I have a TCP connection and a StreamWriter.

```
public void SendData(string data, TcpClient client)
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
    writer.WriteLine(data);
    writer.Flush();
}
```

When I call SendData() subsequently like this

```
SendData("hi", client);
SendData("how are you", client);
SendData("?", client);
```

the client only receives the first line. I added a Thread.Sleep(100) to the SendData() method like this:

```
public void SendData(string data, TcpClient client)
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
    writer.WriteLine(data);
    writer.Flush();
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

The second case works perfectly fine. Do you think my solution is acceptable or should i try to change the client? Do you have any experience or ideas about the origin of this problem?

Comment: Can you try `using(var writer = new StreamWriter(client.getStream())){SendData("Hi",write);SendData("How are you?",writer);SendData("?",writer);}`?

Comment: using calls Dispose() on the writer and destroys the underlying stream. Sadly not an option for a tcp connection

Comment: :( yes if you are using it somewhere else as well or need it later. **But** can you try creating `StreamWriter` outside and pass to `SendData` as suggested by @Matthias247, it will create only one writer.

Comment: this is a nice convention and i implemented it. thank you for your help but the problem is still unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client is listening in Unity in a function called Update(), which is being called every frame. If you send twice the second data will be sent between two frames and can't be received. The thread.sleep is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should normally not create multiple StreamWriters on top of a single `TcpClient/NetworkStream`. As you can see in the documentation of `StreamWriter` it expects to take ownership of the wrapped `Stream` and will call `Dispose` on it once you `Dispose` the `StreamWriter`. You should create either only a single `StreamWriter` and use this to send all your lines, or you have to create the `StreamWriter`s with the `leaveOpen` flag set to true - which allows you could `Dispose` them without the disposing the `TcpClient` accidently.

This doesn't directly answer why the additional lines do not get received. I might guess that it has to do something with buffering inside the `StreamWriter` which isn't fully flushed until the stream is disposed. So I would try to Dispose the StreamWriters and/or create only a single one. Or maybe the reception on the other side is not working correctly? In that case it would be easiest to check with Wireshark, tcpdump or strace what really gets written to the socket.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I changed the code accordingly and it looks cleaner. The problem still persists though.